# Print barcode using "TSC TTP-244 Pro" printer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, barcode, barcode-printing

Assuming I have a list of strings `var barcodesList = new List<string>();` and filled with some values, I want to generate a barcode for each value in the list (with the barcode type = **Code 128**), then printing all of them using **TSC TTP-244 Pro** printer and the barcode should be 2.5 * 5

Is there any library can help in generating the barcodes?

How to print the generated barcodes?

Comment: The TSC TTP-244 Pro is a barcode printer that emulates Zebra. Why do you need a library to print a barcode?

Comment: I don't need a library to print the barcode, I need a library to help me generating the barcodes. Also, I need to know how to print the generated barcodes; as I don't know how to deal with this printer!

Comment: Connect to printer through a port. Send ZPL out to the printer. It generates the barcodes for you. Here's the ZPL manual: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf. The only reason you need a barcode library if you have a printer that prints barcodes out of the box is if you want to implement a WYSIWYG interface of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around for this, you can export the list of the barcodes to an excel file, then use the Gargour software to import the file and it will generate the barcodes and print them.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a few candidate and widely used libraries exist, depending on the driver types available for the TSC printer.

For win32 .NET apps, you can use your strings along with the Pos for .NET SDK to generate and print directly to the printer https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55758 . You will need an OPOS service object from the TSC manufacturer.

For UWP apps: 
If no OPOS service object (driver) for the TSC, you can generate barcode bitmaps (code128 and others) using the wallet barcode API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.walletbarcode. From there, you will need to render the bitmap to your TSC using the page printer API https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing

If you can find an OPOS service object (driver) for the TSC, it is straightforward to generate and print using the PosPrinter API https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter